# Difference between UIaComWrapper and UIAutomationCLient + UIAutomationType

Tags: c#

I am writing automation scripts using codedui.

Which dll should I Use?

UIaComWrapper

or

UIAutomationCLient + UIAutomationType

Problem I am facing is:

AutomatinElement.GetClickablepoint () will return drawing.point if UIAComWrapper is used. It will return Windows.Point if UIAutomationCLient + UIAutomationType dlls are referenced.

Can any one guide me, which one shall I use for my codedUI scripts?

Answer (score 2):

More or less they both are same and they use same namespace and same name classes too, the points where they do differ are;

1. `UIACOMWrapper.dll` uses **UnManaged API** that could be one of the reasons that it is way too much fast than `UIAutomationClient.dll` Moreover, it is open source so there are many time to time enhancements to make it perform bit more effieceint.
2. `UIAutomationClient.dll` is an outdated assembly based upon **Managed API**, it is slower than `UIACOMWrapper`, new versions of VS has no support of it.

If you want to analyze the behavior of UIACOMWrapper then use UIA Verify tool, use UIA Spy for UIAutoamtionClient.

Hope this will help,
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It is depending on which version of visual studio your using to develop tests.
UIAComwrapper is used for VS2013 and above.
Microsoft was updated syntax of AutomatinElement.GetClickablepoint () in UIAComwrapper
There some more in UIAComwrapper.

Regards,
Rajendar